# Not understanding vhdl online compiler error

Tags: vhdl, digital-logic

i am using an inline compiler (https://www.edaplayground.com/) and im not understanding the online compilers error message. I am trying to build the boolean expression `(a * !b) + (b * !c) + (!b * c)`.

**My code is:**

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

ENTITY (MySimp) IS
PORT (A: in STD_LOGIC;
      B: in STD_LOGIC;
      C: in STD_LOGIC;
      Z: out STD_LOGIC;
 );
End MySimp;

ARCHITECTURE (details) OF (MySimp) IS
BEGIN 
PROCESS
VARIABLE D, E, F: STD_LOGIC;
BEGIN
IF A AND (NOT B)= '1' THEN D:= '1';
ELSE D:= '0';
END IF:

IF B AND (NOT C)= '1' THEN E:= '1';
ELSE E:= '0';
END IF:

IF C AND (NOT B)= '1' THEN F:= '1';
ELSE F:= '0';
END IF:

Z <= D OR E OR F;

END PROCESS;
END details;
```

[image: ErrorMessage]

Comment: from the error message and the .sv, I would bet you tried to compile the code as (system) verilog instead of VHDL!

Comment: I am not familiar with this compiler, thank you. Now im getting a different error message:                                                                 Aldec, Inc. VHDL Compiler, build 2017.02.99
VLM Initialized with path: "/home/runner/library.cfg".
DAGGEN WARNING DAGGEN_0523: "The source is compiled without the -dbg switch. Line breakpoints and assertion debug will not be available."
COMP96 File: design.vhd
COMP96 File: testbench.vhd
COMP96 ERROR COMP96_0018: "Identifier expected." "design.vhd" 4 8
COMP96 ERROR COMP96_0016: "Design unit declaration expected." "design.vhd" 4 9

Comment: COMP96 ERROR COMP96_0018: "Identifier expected." "design.vhd" 13 14
COMP96 ERROR COMP96_0016: "Design unit declaration expected." "design.vhd" 13 15
COMP96 ERROR COMP96_0016: "Design unit declaration expected." "testbench.vhd" 4 0
COMP96 Compile failure 5 Errors 0 Warnings  Analysis time :  0.0 [ms]
Exit code expected: 0, received: 1

Comment: I never saw the name of the objects, here the entity, being in (). Remove them, it's exactly at line 4 char 8 as the error says

Comment: same for the architecture name and more

Comment: From the image link for your error message you've told whatever tool that you've provided a SystemVerilog design when in fact you've provided a VHDL design incidentally [containing syntax and semantic errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3kRt.jpg).

Comment: Note your process is also missing a process sensitivity list. Not an error but will prevent simulation finishing. The process will never suspend. Simulator vendors sometimes include a method of detecting the problem.

Comment: One of the great things about EDA Playground is that it allows you to share your code by posting its URL, eg https://www.edaplayground.com/x/9 .Were you to do that, we could see what you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

As the error shows, you are compiling a VHDL file (.vhd) as a (System) Verilog file (.sv). Those are two different hardware description languages.
In the `Languages and Libraries` tab on the left, you need to set the `Testbench + Design` to `VHDL`.

But there's a problem in your code. The `process` statement doesn't have a [sensitivity list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27764955/6717178). HDLs are usually parallel languages, which means you need to indicate when a process needs to be triggered: else it will try to loop indefinitely in an infinitesimal time. You either need to add a `wait`-statement, to stop the loop, or implicitly do that by adding the trigger signals to the process sensitivity list. e.g.

```
process (a,b,c)
```

There are more semantical issues with your code. I added them in comments

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity MySimp is -- no braces around the name
    port (
        a: in  std_logic;
        b: in  std_logic;
        c: in  std_logic;
        z: out std_logic -- no semicolon
    );
end entity;

architecture arch of MySimp is
begin 
    process(a, b, c)
        variable d, e, f: std_logic;
    begin
        if (a and (not b))= '1' then -- add braces around the logic expression
            d:= '1';
        else
            d:= '0';
        end if; -- semicolon instead of colon

        -- alternative method 1
        if b='1' and c='0' then
            e:= '1';
        else
            e:= '0';
        end if;

        -- alternative method 2
        f := c and (not b);

        z <= d or e or f;
    end process;
    -- or replace the whole process by:
    --z <= (a and (not b)) or (b xor c);
    -- as (b and (not c)) or (c and (not b)) is an exclusive-or operation
end architecture;
```